# Does minified JavaScript code improve performance?

Tags: javascript

I'm making an [AIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime) application (so the download time doesn't have a huge impact). Does combining and minifing all the JavaScript files affect the performance? How would obfuscating affect the performance?

Comment: I'm making an AIR application (for offline use), thus download time isn't a big factor.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody's mentioned that modern JS runtimes have heuristics applying different parsing and optimization levels for functions based on their *raw source code length*. See e.g., https://github.com/nolanlawson/optimize-js#why and references there but you might see microbenchmarks showing ~10% runtime difference between the original function vs its minified representation. Compilers move on, and things might change, so always benchmark yourself!, but do consider what magic JS engines do when pondering performance.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Minifying improves performance for your page overall by decreasing the load time (even if only slightly).

Neither minifying nor obfuscating alter the execution time by any perceivable amount **for the vast majority of JavaScript code out there.**

I do recommend minifying for those reasons and more. Minifying multiple scripts together (like jQuery and its plugins) can yield even greater savings.

As pointed out, on constrained devices and/or with very *large* codebases minifying could yield a noticeable result.

Comment: Sorry, down voted - Minifying means that there is less text to parse and variables take up less memory (and are quicker to compare, hash etc) so there can be a considerable improvement in both speed and memory usage - escpecially important on constrained devices.

Comment: On second thoughts I have reversed my down vote -  I do not know enough about the particular javascript in AIR so may be wrong. But certainly with some javascript engines minifying can make a big difference on large applications.

Comment: You are right, though the cases where that would be true are few and far between. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I think we might be suffering confusion about what "minify" means - it is sometimes used just to describe taking out extra white space (as with jsmin) and comments but leaving the variable names the same and some "minifiers" (like packer) go further and shorten variable names as well. Obviously the first only affect download and initial parsing of code whereas the second type affect run-time performance as well.

Comment: Minified JS has no improvement in JS *runtime* if anything it causes performance reduction as the decompression methods used by some minification libraries defeat a number of optimisations made in modern JS engines.

Obfuscating also impacts performance as it deliberately makes convoluted JS which differs from "normal" execution pattern.  A good obfuscator can actually optimise perf, but i've seen obfuscators that as much as halve performance.

In general variable and property name length is no longer a contributing factor in JS perf due to the many and varied caching methods in JS impls now.

Comment: @Dipstick, please read olliej's comment (#5), as it invalidates your comment. even if you are somehow right and he is wrong, still the performance gain cannot be said to be "considerable" but probably "negligible"

Comment: This is not true anymore in 2021 with HTTP/2 enabled.

Comment: honestly it's all theoretical speculation without data. As with anything to do with performance, the answer is "you should measure it and see for yourself if it matters".

It really doesn't matter what can or can't increase or decrease performance in theory, what matters if there is an affect on user experience and/or software infrastructure costs. Making assumptions with this kind of stuff isn't a great idea, even if it's correct in theory. Just too many moving pieces involved to estimate accurately.

Answer (score 28):

#### Minification

Minification does improve performance for two reasons:

- Reduced file-size (because it removes comments and unnecessary white spaces), so your script loads faster. Even if it is embedded into the `<head>`.
- It is parsed faster, since comments and white spaces don't have to be explicitly ignored (since they're not there).

#### Combining

I've written quite a few HTML/JavaScript AIR applications, and from personal experience, combining files won't make a difference. In fact, it's good practice to separate the script based on certain criteria (classes, global functions, SQL functions, etc.). It helps keep them organised when the project becomes too big.

#### Obfuscation

Obfuscating is usually a combination of minification and renaming variables. It involves using `eval` to blow up the code again. This reduces performance for obvious reasons, but it depends on the size of your code.

I'd suggest running tests to understand this best for your specific situation.

Comment: *"In fact, it's good practice to separate script based on certain criteria [which] helps keep them organised when the project becomes too big."* -- I know this answer is near a decade old, but minification and code-packing should be done by a _build tool_, such as webpack. You keep your files organized, then combine them to a _bundle_ file (or more bundle files, in some cases), and then distribute that bundle file only.

Answer (score 9):

Everyone here already talked about minifying, but nobody talked about the second part of your question - combining. This will definitely improve performance, probably even more than minifying.

Multiple files require multiple HTTP requests, so when you put them all into one file, only one request is needed. This is important for two reasons:

- each individual HTTP request may take longer to load for various routing reasons, and one file will potentially delay your whole application.
- browsers and other clients have a maximum limit of files they are allowed to download concurrently from a single domain. Depending on the number of files in your application, this may mean the client queuing them up, thus making the load even longer.

Also, besides minifying and combining, you have to absolutely make sure you have some sort of server-side compression enabled. This can **save you 90% or even more** in the amount of bytes transferred, depending on the files.

You can read more about compression (gzip, deflate) in *[How to make your site lightning fast by compressing (deflate/gzip) your HTML, JavaScript, CSS, XML, etc. in Apache](http://beerpla.net/2009/06/09/how-to-make-your-site-lightning-fast-by-compressing-deflategzip-your-html-javascript-css-xml-etc-in-apache/)*.

Comment: He's pointed out that it's an AIR app, hence there aren't any HTTP connections. In AIR apps, it's better to classify and separate script so that they're more organised. The more the better actually.

Comment: Ah, I assumed his AIR app communicates with a remote server, which hosts the files.

Comment: minification and combination is not an issue with `HTML/2`, as it can can handle multiple file without stacking them up.

Comment: @nicoX Think you mean `HTTP/2` m80, HTML has nothing to do with the server hosting it :)

Answer (score 4):

Minification does not improve the speed at which JavaScript *executes* at runtime, which I believe it what you're really interested in.  In fact, if you use Packer's Base64 compression, it's actually slower on initial load.

Minification will reduce the size of the JavaScript though, making your application's download size smaller.

Answer (score 3):

Minifying strips out all comments, superfluous white space and shortens variable names.  It thus reduces download time for your JavaScript files as they are (usually) a lot smaller in filesize.  So, yes it does improve performance.

The obfuscation  shouldn't adversely affect performance.

The article *[Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)* talks about minifying.

Comment: Minification does *not* shorten variable names.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to post this as a separate answer as it somewhat contrasts the accepted one:

Yes, it does make a performance difference as it reduces parsing time - and that's often the critical thing. For me, it was even just simply linear in the size and I could get it from 12 seconds to 4 seconds parse time by minifying from 3 MB to 1 MB.

It's not a big application either. It just has a couple of reasonable dependencies.

So the moral of the story here is: Yes, minifying is important for performance - and *not* because of bandwidth, but because of parsing.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](https://www.programmerinterview.com/javascript/what-is-javascript-minification/):

**Minification** in JavaScript is the process of removing all characters that are not necessary from the JavaScript source code. That is why it is called “minification” – because all of the data that is not necessary to the functioning of the JavaScript is removed from the source code, and therefore the JavaScript is “minimized”. Even though these characters are removed from the JavaScript source code, the functionality of the JavaScript code does not change at all.

So, your JavaScript code will behave exactly the same even after it goes through the minification process. Code that has gone through the minification process is also known as “minified” code

**What are the benefits and advantages of JavaScript minification**

The main purpose of JavaScript minification is to speed up the downloading or transfer of the JavaScript code from the server hosting the website’s JavaScript. The reason that minification makes downloads go faster is because it reduces the amount of data (in the minified JavaScript file) that needs to be downloaded. Less data means that the user’s browser spends less time processing that data, which is why time is saved. So, we can say that minification is performed on JavaScript source code because it is essentially a performance enhancement – and it allows websites that use minified JavaScript to load faster.