# Why first operation in my application is slow?

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, entity-framework, windows-store-apps

I have a windows store apps 8 application.

*My Application structure:*

- Server Side - WCF Server which has a reference to the DAL - Entity Framework using a Repository Pattern, it accesses to the SQL DB (for now it is local database and using Database First).
- Client Side - Windows Store Apps 8 which uses 2 services - one is mine, the other is of Bing Maps.

So when I start my application, first the server is up, then the application shows the login page - everything is ok until now.

Next -> I sign in to the application (through Facebook API). And **here is the problem** - it takes something like 25 seconds the first time I sign in and redirected to the Main Page.

When it redirects to the main page - it loads a bing map and goes to my WCF service for a small operation (that takes less then second).

*Note:* I would think that my code is not correct but if I sign out and then again sign in, the second time takes less then 5 seconds.

What could be the cause to its slowness?

Comment: If I would have to hunt this bug, I would use a performance profiler (like e.g. [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)).

Answer (score 0):

I think because your app load alot of css and js at the first time. Second time load, browser already loaded libs,

Comment: I am not using any css or js... But yes the cause can be the loading of it, and the second time maybe it saves in the cache so it is faster. But how to check if it is true? And if it is true - how to do it faster :)

Comment: @MishaZaslavsky you could minify the css and the js files so they load faster. Read this question about minifying if you want to know more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181447/does-minified-javascript-improve-performance

Comment: @1ntello I don't have css and js files