# Is there a need to use various peformance optimization techniques when using html5 appcache?

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase

I have an Angular/Firebase/Mongo webapp. Designed to be downloaded to home page and run as a "local" app. My question is if I am already caching the files normally requested from the server via the html5 appcache, do I need to concat, minify and use techniques like template caching?  All of these techniques are all designed to minimize the amount and frequency of server calls.  Since the app is getting these locally, is there still a benefit to these optimizations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does minified javascript improve performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181447/does-minified-javascript-improve-performance)

Comment: The answers to that question only partially address this question. I do understand that there will be less memory used but the question of difference in load efficiency given a webapp's html5 resolving via webcache is not addressed nor Angular specific templateCaching.  Nor the value of reducing http calls that are being resolved locally.

Comment: Combining the files will have no effect. Minifying them will have a really small initial effect (parsing the code will be a bit faster due to removed comments and whitespace). That's all written in the answers. There will _not_ be less memory used, that is if you are running your app in a modern browser with acceptable garbage collection after parsing the code. Template caching does not benefit from minifying JS as strings are not minified. The value of no HTTP calls is obvious, I don't understand what can be discussed about that. Also, appcache loading speed >>> HTTP loading speed.

Comment: Let me expand on template caching. The whole purpose of using Angular's template cache is so that it does not have to request a HTML resource each time it needs it, so you embed them in a JS file. Thus instead of N HTTP calls you end up with just one for all your templates. Combine that JS file with all the rest and extra HTTP calls for templates are reduced to 0. So exactly like when you are using HTML5 appcache (0 HTTP calls for templates). Minifying does not help here because templates are stored as JS strings that cannot be minified.

Comment: Ok. So you are confirming what I believed to be true.  Essentially,  if you are running with a HTML5 appcache then there will be very little performance benefit to: minifying, templateCaching and concatenation.  Correct?  Have you tested this?

Comment: I confirm and yes I have tested this. Be warned though that there is a cache limit imposed by some browsers (eg.: Safari for iOS, Chrome for Windows) ranging from 5 to 50MB. If you use a lot of large libraries it might be a good idea to minify them even if you eventually serve them from appcache. In Chrome there's a Quota Manager that you need to use to request additional storage space.