# Does minifying JavaScript have a slower execution time?

Tags: javascript, optimization, jsperf

I was testing whether minified JavaScript performs better on mobile devices. While researching the topic I came across this jsperf test:

http://jsperf.com/minified-vs-crushed/2

According to this test removing the whitespace speeds up execution but minifying the code actually makes it run slower. I know that minified should speed up loading times but does it make execution times slower? Is there something that I am not understanding here?

Further reading:

[Does minified javascript improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181447/does-minified-javascript-improve-performance)

Comment: Only thing I can think of there would be that this minifier is taking shortcuts by introducing more expensive operations such as the ternary operator(`bool?true-result:false-result`) over a traditional if condition. This is pretty much a best guess sort of thing though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a bad JSPerf - whichever test you put first will run the fastest.  I switched the order here: http://jsperf.com/minified-vs-crushed/5

When creating a JSPerf, you need to be careful not to do anything that will modify the context in a way that might throw off later tests.  This code is obviously changing the environment (ie. adding event listeners) causing later tests to take longer to run.

So to answer your question:  No, minifying JS does not cause slower execution times.

Comment: So would removing the event listeners after every test fix this then?

Comment: Assuming that they are the only thing changing the environment, then yes; however, I didn't look too thoroughly for other potential issues.