# vue js minified vs not minified performance

Tags: vue.js

I have project, it has some high performance web page:

For example, I have àrray of items which have up to 20k elements which I need to render

I can't use pagination due to client requirements.

The thing is that I include vue js via inline script

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

And I have some performance issues(browser simply can't render so many items fast enough(and we are talking not about only rendering but interactively changing them)

But I wonder, if I move to including vue js as npm module, and using a production minified file

Will it be significant boost in performance?
If yes - how many percent?
(I am asking this, cause I have just one high loaded page, so I am fine with vue js included only on it)

Comment: You might get a minute decrease in the time it takes to load the vue library, but the time it takes to render those 20k elements won't be affected by how vue is being loaded.

Comment: If you cant paginate, you can always use live-scroll, and i believe it will fix your performance issues. I dont think its about vue, its about heavy data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does minified javascript improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181447/does-minified-javascript-improve-performance)

Comment: We cannot answer this for you.  You need to profile yourself.  However, if the bottleneck is the overhead required to be reactive, I don't think reducing the size of the library is really going to help.  However, that's why you need to actually profile the differences.