# Why is javascript written in width

Tags: javascript

Why do programmers write javascript like this?

```
function(e){function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var o=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return....
```

Not like that

````js
function(e) {
    function n(r) {
        if (t[r]) return t[r].exports;
        var o = t[r] = {
            i: r,
            l: !1,
            exports: {}
        };
        return```
````

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: They don't write it like that, they write it normally and then there's tools that automatically minify it for you to reduce the size of the file.

Comment: Why these techniques evolved the way they did involves a lot of history but when considering these links and answers, it is worth considering that, for practical purposes, the delivery mechanism for JavaScript programs has been restricted to source code. This hasn't changed in the language's 24 years.

Comment: Thank you for this information

Answer (score 3):

The programmer didn't write like that. They have used minification tools to improve the performance of their app. So the less load will be put on browser

Answer (score 1):

it's a minified version of js
if you want to view unminify code you can use this online tool https://www.unminify2.com/

also, you can see the benefit of minified js on this [Does minified javascript improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181447/does-minified-javascript-improve-performance?noredirect=1&lq=1)